# WSDL Api in Php

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I want to develop WSDL services in the PHP.

I have created one PHP file `index.php`, I have called `hello.wsdl` file by SOAP.

Code is here:

```
 <?php 
        $client = new soapclient('`http://localhost/test/hello.wsdl`');
        $response=$client->addSubscriber('EMtest', 44983, 'name@example.com', 'Name');
        echo $response;
    ?>
```

My `hello.wsdl` file code is here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <definitions name="MyDefinition" 
     targetNamespace="urn:myTargetNamespace"
     xmlns:tns="urn:myTns"   
     xmlns:xsd="`http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`" 
     xmlns:soap="`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/`" 
     xmlns="`http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/`">
     <message name="addSubscriberRequest">
        <part name="api_key" type="xsd:string"/>
        <part name="group_id" type="xsd:int"/>
        <part name="email" type="xsd:string"/>
        <part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
     </message>
        <message name="addSubscriberResponse">
        <part name="error" type="tns:ErrorTypeEnum"/>
     </message>

     <operation name="addSubscriber

">
 <input message="tns:addSubscriberRequest"/>
 <output message="tns:addSubscriberResponse"/>
```

But I am not able to get soap request response...
I have got some errors, like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '`http://localhost/test/hello.php?wsdl`' : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/test/index.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/test/index.php(39): SoapClient->SoapClient('`http://localhost...`') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/test/index.php on line 39
```

Please guide me on how to call SOAP and how to create WSDL service in PHP,
also please correct my code...

Answer (score 0):

Your WSDL is incomplete there is a lot more work to do. I would suggest that you first start modelling your request and response operations using a XSD then import that XSD into a WSDL and use it from there.

You will need a decent WSDL editor like Altova XML Spy or Liquid XML Studio. Below is an example of what your minimum WSDL needs to look like. I would suggest that you compare this skeleton to yours and understand the differences.

Things you are missing are:

- Schema(XSD) information around request, response and object passed to these operations.
- Port definition
- Service definition
- Bindings.

If you are serious about using web-services understanding these basic concepts are crucial. I suggest that you get to understand these concepts first then come back when you have specific problems we can address.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Hello"
              targetNamespace="http://mycompanyurl.com/HelloService_v1"
              xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
              xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
              xmlns:tns="http://mycompanyurl.com/HelloService_v1"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
              xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
               targetNamespace="http://example.com/">
        <xs:element name="InputType">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="input"
                                type="string" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="OutputType">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="output"
                                type="string" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="addSubscriberRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="InputMessagePart"
               element="tns:InputType" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="addSubscriberResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="OutputMessagePart"
               element="tns:OutputType" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="HelloServicePortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="addSubscriber">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:addSubscriberRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:addSubscriberResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="HelloHTTPBinding"
             type="tns:HelloServicePortType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
                  style="document" />
    <wsdl:operation name="addSubscriber">
        <wsdl:input />
        <wsdl:output />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="HelloService">
    <wsdl:port name="HelloPort"

               binding="tns:HelloHTTPBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://mycompanyurl.helloservice.com" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```